# how do i add the text into the array in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

Im trying to add new text into an array from an EditText when a user clicks a add button.
So far i have got hard coded text from my Strings file but i want to be able to add new categories when the user types it in the edittext field and presses the add button

This is my class:

```
package com.example.myapplication

import android.content.Context
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.EditText
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.example.myapplication.Model.MyModel
import com.example.myapplication.adapters.Category

class Profile : AppCompatActivity() {

lateinit var category: EditText
lateinit var add: Button
lateinit var categoryList: RecyclerView

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile)

    category = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.add_category)
    add = findViewById<Button>(R.id.add_button)



    //Set Recycler view
    val categoryModelArrayList = populateList()

    val recyclerView =  findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.categoryLists)
    val layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
    recyclerView.layoutManager = layoutManager

    val adapter = Category(categoryModelArrayList)
    recyclerView.adapter = adapter



    add.setOnClickListener {

        val newCategory = category.text.toString().trim()
        val isValid = validateCategory(newCategory)

        if (isValid) {
            dismissKeyBoard()
            Toast.makeText(this, "$newCategory has been added to your list of following", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

            //Need to add $newCategory to the following list when the user clicks on the add button

        }
    }
}

private fun populateList() : ArrayList<MyModel> {

    val list = ArrayList<MyModel>()
    val categoryList = arrayOf(R.string.app_name, R.string.bottom_sheet_behavior, R.string.saved_articles)
    val size = categoryList.size

    for (i in categoryList.indices) {
        val categoryModel = MyModel()
        categoryModel.setCategories(getString(categoryList[i]))
        list.add(categoryModel)
    }
    return list
}

private fun validateCategory(newCategory:String): Boolean {

    if(newCategory.isEmpty()) {
        category.setError("Category is required")
        return false
    }
    return true
}

private fun dismissKeyBoard() {
    val view = this.currentFocus
    if (view != null) {
        val imm = getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.windowToken, 0)
    }
}
```

}

so for i am just using string that exist in my strings file of my app but i want to be able to add new strings when the user presses the add button but when i try to add the new string it says it expects an Int instead of a String and i am not sure why

How would i add new string to this array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're creating an array of Int here

```
val categoryList = arrayOf(R.string.app_name, R.string.bottom_sheet_behavior, R.string.saved_articles)
```

`R.string.anything` is an integer id of the resource, not the resource itself.

If you want a String array containing the actual values you need something like this:

```
val categoryList = arrayOf(
    getString(R.string.app_name), 
    getString(R.string.bottom_sheet_behavior), 
    getString(R.string.saved_articles)
)
```